# Javascript to check "Acess Your Location" is "Bloacked Temporarily"

Tags: javascript, geolocation

How can I get status of location permission in Firefox by javascript if user **temporarily** blocked/allowed the request in the past. (in firefox they don't choose "Remember this selection").

I using below code to check geolocation permission, but in both case **temporarily** blocked/allowed, it return state: "prompt"

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' })
        .then(function(data) {
            if(typeof data == 'object' && data.state != void 0) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

How I can do to get the "temporarily" status? Thank

Comment: You probably can't. What if you get a "permanent" permission, but then the user goes into their browser's settings and removes the permission again? In other words, there's no guarantee even a "permanent" permission is permanent. So what good does it do to differentiate? You must be prepared to lose permission at any time. You can only know whether you have permission right now.

Comment: Yes, what I want just only want to know "right now" permission is blocked or granted.